# Unhook remove_non_recurring_fees() WooCommerce Subscriptions function

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

I'm desperately trying to remove an action while the cart calculates the total.

Here is my code:

```
remove_action('woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', array('WCS_Cart_Renewal', 'remove_non_recurring_fees'), 1000);
```

While the original action hook is taking place on the WooCommerce Subscriptions plugin:

```
// Remove non-recurring fees from renewal carts. Hooked in late (priority 1000), to ensure we handle all fees added by third-parties.
        add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', array( $this, 'remove_non_recurring_fees' ), 1000 );
```

Unfortunately I could not remove the `remove_non_recurring_fees` hooked function.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When you Look at [`WCS_Cart_Renewal` Class and `remove_non_recurring_fees()` function](https://github.com/wp-premium/woocommerce-subscriptions/blob/master/includes/class-wcs-cart-renewal.php#L1191-L1229), you will see that this function removes all fees first and re-add only recurring fees, when a subscription is involved. This function is hooked with a priority of 1000.

Instead of trying to remove the action hook that trigger this function, you have 2 other choices:

**1). For custom fees added by you via your theme's `functions.php` file:**

You will have just to use a greater priority like in this following example:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'my_custom_fee', 2000 );
function my_custom_fee( $cart ) {
     // Your code
}
```

**2). Or better using `woocommerce_subscriptions_is_recurring_fee` available filter hook:**

This filter hook that allows to re-add all desired fees that are not recurring with this simple code line:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_subscriptions_is_recurring_fee', '__return_true' );
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.